# Consolidate quantity of identical items

Tags: javascript, loops

I have array of items with values like below:-

```
 item[0] A    quantity[0]       10       Category[0]  Alpha    itemtype[0]   Groceries
 item[1] A    quantity[1]       15       Category[1]  Beta     itemtype[1]   Toiletries
 item[2] B    quantity[2]       5        Category[2]  Alpha    itemtype[2]   Stationery
```

Using Javascript, I wanted to consolidate the quantity for identical items, plus it should only show item type where category is Alpha if there are few identical items. The result of the new arrays should be :

```
 item[0] A       quantity[0] 25      category[0] Alpha      itemtype[0]Groceries
 item[1] B       quantity[1] 5       category[1] Alpha      itemtype[1]Stationery
```

Comment: Is that only one array ? or a few arrays (item, quantity, etc.) ? Are the elements of item only strings ?

Comment: Sorry, few arrays. Yes, only strings

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
// create JS-objects to collect the values ...
var i,nam,quant={},cat={},ityp={};
for (i=0; i<item.length; i++) {
  nam=item[i];
  // initialise the summation variable to zero first:
  if (typeof quant[nam]=='undefined') quant[nam]=0;
  // do the summation
  quant[nam]+=quantity[i];

  // initialise the string variables too:
  if (typeof ityp[nam]=='undefined') ityp[nam]='';
  if (typeof  cat[nam]=='undefined')  cat[nam]='';
  if (category[i]=='Alpha') { // set the variables, if ...
    ityp[nam]=itemtype[i];
    cat[nam]=category[i];    
  }
}
// destroy original arrays ...
category=[];item=[];quantity=[];itemtype=[];
// ... and build them up again:
for (i in quant) {
  item.push(i);
  quantity.push(quant[i]);
  category.push(cat[i]);
  itemtype.push(ityp[i]);  
}
```

This approach does not rely on any given order of the elements in the arrays.

See here for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CP2cQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0, l = category.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (category[i + 1] !== category[i]) {
        category.splice(i + 1, 1);
        item.splice(i + 1, 1);
        quantity[i] = String(+quantity[i] + +quantity[i + 1]);
        quantity.splice(i + 1, 1);
        itemtype.splice(i + 1, 1);
    }
    i--; l--;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwUW4/1/)

You can also add the separate arrays to a wrapper, and loop over that with `forEach` (IE9 and above IIRC):

```
var arrays = [ category, item , quantity, itemtype ];

for (var i = 0, l = category.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (category[i + 1] !== category[i]) {
        quantity[i] = String(+quantity[i] + +quantity[i + 1]);
        arrays.forEach(function (el) { return el.splice(i + 1, 1); });
    }
    i--; l--;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwUW4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to use array of objects like

```
var items = [
    {item: 'A', quantity: 10, category: 'Alpha', itemtype: 'Groceries'},
    {item: 'A', quantity: 15, category: 'Beta', itemtype: 'Toiletries'},
    {item: 'B', quantity: 5, category: 'Alpha', itemtype: 'Stationery'}
]
```

then filter it

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    if (items[i].category == "Alpha"){
        result.push(items[i]);
    }
}
```

`result` is your new array.